# Create a circle using a Catmull-Rom Spline

Tags: c#, math, spline

I have a class where you enter control points for a catmull-rom spline, and then it returns a list of points running along the spline.

What points would I need to enter to create a circle?

Comment: Isn't it by definition _cubic_? How would you get a circle, which is quadratic?

Comment: You won't be able to create a circle, only an approximation.

Comment: Ok thanks! An approximation would be fine, do you know what the closest is that I'll be able to get?

Comment: Ok never mind! I found that using a bunch of points on the circle works well enough for what I want. I didn't fully understand what a Catmull-Rom spline did!